# After Update to Android Studio version 4.0.1 the ADB wont recognise USB device

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

Following a recent software update including Android Studio (3.5 - 4.0.1) on my Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (Linux 5.4.0-42-generic x86_64) system the adb doesn't detect a USB device namely my Phone I use for testing Apps.
I had no problem with this on Android Studio v3.5. My Phone is automatically recognised by Ubuntu and I can see my device is loaded in my Files manager, hence there is no problem with the USB device or cable.   I have set all the required Developer options on my Phone including USB debugging and Unknown Sources and tried using the Connection Assistant but it says "No devices detected".  In the Connection Assistant I have also tried the Restart ADB Server option, but the problem persists.  Also the user I am logged in with has the required privileges including "plugdev" and the ADB is running correctly since I created an AVD and my app run on the virtual device without any issues.

Additional. On my Phone changed "Use USB connection" from File Transfer to Photo Transfer, received a dialog on my phone asking whether to accept an RSA key that allows debugging through this computer and checked the "Always allow this computer" option. In Android Studio I reran the Connection Assistant and Restarted the ADB Server, then my device was detected, however Its clear that my apk will be unable to install as  Android Studio will require it to be in File transfer mode.  So I switched it back over to that, but then my USB device disappears in Android Studio, but at least its ruled out a lot of potential causes.

Comment: I installed android studio 3.5.3 and found that I could only get android studio to detect the usb device if I switched the usb connection options on my phone to Photo Transfer then in a stranger twist the apk installed and launched on my device and this is my temporary workaround.   This problem seems to be a bug that appears to have manifested in around version 3.5.3 since I had an earlier build and never experienced any of these issues.

Comment: Have you tried on a different phone and different cable, and do you have usb debugging enabled on your device?

Comment: Did you read the question in its entirety?  As per my findings in both the question and my comment, I have eliminated any developer option settings/hardware issues, since the adb detects and identifies my phone over the cable when I switch to photo transfer mode in version 4.0.1.   Using Android Studio v3.5.3 I can install my apk's though only when I switch to Photo Transfer mode, so evidently this is a software issue/bug and prior to the update I was using the same phone, only I have recently purchased a new cable from a reputable retailer so I was pretty sure this wasn't a hardware issue.